# UITextField not aligning center

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitextfield

Background: This is iOS 8, both the simulator and iPad2, Objective-C not swift, all UI is coded not storyboard.

I want my UITextField to be aligned in the center, vertically and horizontally before, during and after editing.

This is what i'm doing:

```
[textfield setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[textfield setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
[textfield setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
```

It looks good during editing, but not before.

Before editing, it's left aligned:

[image]

When beginning editing it's properly centered:

[image]

And if the new text is longer than the old text, it's like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has a similar issue and wants to know what I did, I do not have a solution to the problem with UITextField, i'm guessing it's a bug on Apple's end, so I switched to UITextView, and that works.